# How can I append a hash to a UIWebView location href?

Tags: javascript, ipad, uiwebview, href

I have iPad application where I load a local html into a UIWebView. How can I append a hash tag to the URL, so that the hash tag to the web view href so that it is there from start?

What I want to do is:

1. Load the html page from local file
2. Append a hash tag to the UIWebview href
3. Inject the html into the web view
4. Display the page

Answer (score 0):

1) Use UIWebView's loadHTMLString:baseURL: method. See past posting for details

2) I presume the hash tag is used in step 4, if not provide further details why its at step 2 but you don't display the page until step 4. You can do this using Javascript.

3) You need to execute Javascript which will alter the dom.

4) Again using Javascript, do a location change. If you load the page again using loadHTMLString:baseURL you'll just get the original page again.

So you need to do a lot of execution of Javascript, the method to do that is UIWebView's stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:. See past postings for details. If you're loading the page to jump to the hash tag then just add the hash tag here and not in a separate step 2.